# PHP replace a day number with a variable

Tags: php, date

I have this code:

```
$x = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($post['commissionEligibilityDate'] . "+ " . $post['billingPeriodExpiration'] . " months"))
```

```
$post['commissionEligibilityDate'] = 2011-11-08 <br/>
$post['billingPeriodExpiration'] = 2 <br/>
```

so `$x` returns `2012-01-08`.

I have another variable `$singleDate` and it's equal to `1`. What I am trying to do replace the `08` with `01`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use Y-m-d, you can use Y-m-01 or your variable:

```
$x = date("Y-m-".$singleDate, strtotime($post['commissionEligibilityDate'] . "+ " . $post['billingPeriodExpiration'] . " months"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DateTime class:

```
$d = new DateTime($x);
$year = $d->format('Y');
$month = $d->format('m');

$d->setDate($year, $month, '01');

echo $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: using the above was super awesome, as adding days / months PHP itself handles the proper date and gives accurate result, My scenario was adding date that may change month and even year. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('08','01',$post['commissionEligibilityDate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$explode = explode("-",$post['commissionEligibilityDate']);
$explode[2] = $singleDate;

$post['commissionEligibilityDate'] = implode("-",$explode);

$post['commissionEligibilityDate'] will now echo 2011-11-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost anything is possible with PHP. My suggestion seeing as your looking to only get one number from a date that you consider checking out http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to see the various ways of handling the date() output. As you could easily output a day then add to it $z = date('d', time())+1; for example.

I am not sure what your doing with your dates specifically but to me it sounds like you might have a misconception of what they are, and how to work with them. Basically the short idea of it is, a date defined in a variable is a string. You can make them anyway you want even without the use of date() then store them, as long as they are in the right format when you go to store them ie yyyy-mm-dd you should be fine.